Distribute Points on Faces: what am i doing wrong?
I am having an issue with blender crashing when using the geometry nodes. I am relatively new to blender and very new to geometry nodes so i probably do not fully understand a lot of basic things about it yet.
I am trying to add trees on a map by using the "Distribute Points on Faces" node. But when i add just the "Distribute Points on Faces" node to the mesh, Blender first takes up all the available memory of my pc and then crashes. So i thought the mesh is just to large in scale, or has too many vertices. But when i reduce the number of vertices it still happens. And strangely on other meshes even if they are much larger in size or number of vertices the crash does not happen. Only the one mesh i need it to work on does not work.
Here an example where it works fine:

So i suspect it is not the node itself that has an issue, but my mesh (map). But i don't know what could be wrong with it and how to fix it. The problem occurs instantly when the single node is applied, but also happens when i make complete geometry node on another mesh (that works) and then try to add/move it to the map i want it to be on.
Here the example that crashes the software:

Does anyone have suggestion on what could be wrong with the mesh that makes blender crash when applying the node? And more importantly how i can possibly fix it.
Thanks in advance!

The mesh you have seems too big (I can see it in the dimensions tab), so then you add this node with a default density of 10, Blender adds billions of billions of points, which is too much for your computer's memory.
So try lowering the density or making the mesh smaller.
For a mesh that is larger as you pointed, I can't see the dimensions tab, but it may be small but scaled up. The node setups are applied to the object before scaling.

Thank you! You seem to be completely right. I did not realize i did not apply the scale to the other mesh i used for testing.
I also assumed for some reason that the density was the number of points that would be added. I really don't know why i assumed that, as it does not make sense now i think about it.
I heard somewhere that you should try to model in a 1:1 scale. That does not seem to be realistic for this large of an area. So i guess i will need to scale everything down. Just hope that goes well. Or i'll experiment with a lower density.
Thanks again anyway

Model at 1:1 is a good idea, but you have to keep that in mind through multiple things like the density of the distribute, lights power, camera focal length, ... If you're afraid to have issues like these, you should indeed scale it down. You'll always can tweak some things here and there to have a similar result to a 1:1 scale.
